# @font-face not working locally but works when linked externally

Tags: html, css, font-face

So, I have a .ttf font (plus others) that I'm using for a website, with the code formatted as follows:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: DEP;
    src: local("fonts/DEP/DEP.ttf") format("truetype");
    src: local("fonts/DEP/DEP.woff") format("woff");
    src: local("fonts/DEP/DEP.otf") format("opentype");
    src: url(https://codehs.com/uploads/98892640bda8f3fe5654e3c6d20d5c8c) format("truetype");
}
```

I know it's good to have a fallback link in case the local files fail to load, but I noticed when I was editing the code offline that the local files weren't working. I triple-checked the folder structure, tested the code (minus the external link) on the main site to see if it was just my html previewer, etc etc. I don't understand why it won't link properly.

[My code is also on github](https://github.com/SpiritAxolotl/spiritaxolotl.github.io) if you want to investigate this further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local()` accepts locally installed fonts' system identifier, not path to file, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#specifying_local_font_alternatives

Comment: So then do I replace it with ```url()```? Because that doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: If there is a chance your users could have that font installed on their machines (in version your application need), you can use it's `local()` identifier(s) first, so they wouldn't need to download the webfont. Then use CDN url()s and "application-local" url()s - whichever you prefer first.

Comment: Ahh, so in that case, it's a custom font that the user wouldn't have had installed already. So then what's the appropriate way to link this one without using an external site?

Comment: `url()` paths relative to given style sheet. Just fix the syntax: it must be in a **single** `src` property with concrete URLs/formats separated with commas. There's nothing wrong including external URL in there as well, but if you know you can serve it yourself, CDN is probably not necessary.